# Phonegap - Login button UI Modification

Tags: android, cordova

The following is the code for login button:

```
    <button type="submit" data-theme="a" id="loginButton">Login</button>
```

Now, **i have to increase the Login button size and display at the center of the Page. Please share if any ideas.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ecplise, then you can use the `Layout weight` under the Property section of the button
Or a quicker way would be to set

```
   <button 
    type="submit" 
    data-theme="a" 
    android:layout_width="40dp"  //set size depending on your requirements
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"   
    id="loginButton">

       Login

  </button>
```

EDIT: Sorry, I thought you desired to increase the size of button. For centering it , use
 `RelativeLayout`

```
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <button 
        type="submit" 
        data-theme="a" 
        android:layout_width="40dp"  //set size depending on your requirements
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"   
       id="loginButton">

       Login

    </button> 

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` will center it with respect to the screen

Comment: how to make button center of the page?

Comment: i am using phonegap and HTML to display button. Please help me to centralise phonegap button